# 502 Bad Gateway nginx in Google Cloud

Tags: python, flask, deployment, gcloud

Even I install the

```
pip install flask-wtf
```

into my virtual env and i got tested already and it was okay to run. 
However, when I deploy to google cloud engine, I could not able to do anythings. 
It show the error '502 Bad Gateway nginx' and Google Console tells me '**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wtforms**' and '    **HaltServer: HaltServer 'Worker failed to boot.' 3'**
But i got the code below

```
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
```

already in my main.py. 
Is there any why to figure it out? on google Cloud deploy?

Comment: Are you deploying to App Engine Standard or App Engine Flex. Can you please post your requirements.txt file ?

Comment: @marian.vladoi I did in to App engine Standard. Do i need to deploy in App Engine Flex?

Comment: Could you please share you requirements.txt file ?

Answer (score 0):

You need a folder `app` with this structure:

```
 cd app 
 ls 
 #app.yaml  main.py  requirements.txt
```

Where:

```
cat app.yaml
runtime: python37

cat requirements.txt
Flask==1.1.1
flask-wtf 


cat main.py

from flask import Flask
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    """Return a friendly HTTP greeting."""
    return 'Hello World!'
```

Then inside `app` folder run:

```
gcloud app deploy -q
gcloud app browse 
#Go to https://your-project.appspot.com
#Hello World!
```

SUCCESS!